# Italicized footnote number within equation (with newtx/newpx fonts)

Tags: fonts, footnotes, newtx

I am using footnotes within math mode, with command `\footnotemark`. When I use `newtxtext/newtxmath` or `newpxtext/newpxmath` font packages, the footnote number appears italicized whenever the equation is inside a theorem environment; otherwise the number appears non-italicized.

Minimal Working (Non-)Example  (MWNE):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theo}
\[\frac{\sin x}x=\sin=\bullet\footnotemark\]
\footnotetext{Spanish: ``Pecado''.}
\end{theo}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1} %decreases footnote counter by 1
\[\frac{\cos x}x=\cos=\bullet\footnotemark\]
\footnotetext{Bad Spanish: ``Patada''.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the image of the corresponding footnotes:

[image]

When the font packages mentioned above are removed, footnote numbers appear non-italicized. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: `\textup{\footnotemark}` takes care of it. It is there, however, because the basic style of the theorem is italic.  Try `testing\footnotemark` in non-math mode inside the `theo`... the footnotemark is italic.

Comment: Avoid footnotes in math: the mark will be mistaken for an exponent.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I tested `\footnotemark` in non-math mode inside the theorem environment: the footnote number appeared italicized when I was using the special fonts; otherwise it appeared non-italicized; your suggestion worked, though. If you write that as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: If no one provides something better (an explanation of why the special fonts do this), I can post my `\textup` as an answer if and when you desire it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your advise; the thing is that the university library's Draconian (and nonsense, by the way) rules require numbers as footnotes. Independently of that, Steven B. Segletes' solution covers the eventuality that a footnote symbol appears italicized, don't you think?